# Text to Speech in urdu language in ionic 4

Tags: angular, npm, artificial-intelligence, ionic4

I hope you will be fine. I have a question about Ionic 4 with TTS(text to speech) I tried ionic native plugin but I didn't a solution. I want to create an App that can produce a sound of Urdu Words.

I also use [speak-tts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speak-tts) but didn't solve my problem kindly help me.

I tried with the above NPM package.

```
    export class HomePage {
     speech = new Speech();
     constructor(
        private textToSpeech: TextToSpeech
     ) {
      this.speech.init({
       lang: 'ur-PK'
      }).then((data) => {
       console.log(data);
       console.log('Success !');
      }).catch(e => {
       console.error('An error occurred :', e);
      });
     }
     speach() {
        this.speech.speak({
        text: 'شیر'
     }).then(() => {
      console.log('Success !');
     }).catch(e => {
      console.error('An error occurred :', e);
    });
   }
  }
```

Comment: To see the list of supported languages, use `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices().map(v => v.lang)`. If a language is not there, the client does not have a voice that speaks that language, and there's not much you can do about it. I guess the closest thing you can do is transliterate to Hindi, which has wider voice support.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but I find another solution. I post in Ans

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to above my Question. I convert the Urdu word into roman Urdu English like Urdu words. I use Hindi translate words because it does not sport Pakistan Urdu words. that's why I test the voice and working perfectly for me.

```
export class HomePage {
 speech = new Speech();
 constructor(
  private textToSpeech: TextToSpeech
 ) {
    this.speech.init({
     lang: 'hi-IN'
    }).then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
     console.log('Success !');
    }).catch(e => {
     console.error('An error occurred :', e);
   });
 }
 speach() {
   this.speech.speak({
    text: 'Shair'
   }).then(() => {
      console.log('Success !');
   }).catch(e => {
      console.error('An error occurred :', e);
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it working on app too? It worked while development on browser, but not after becoming an app! ionic 4!

Comment: Can you please tell me the configuration that needs to be updated in the project other than the above mentioned code! Because I'm still facing problem making it speak in app(working fine in chrome browser while development)! I have made its declaration in `src/typings.d.ts` but its still not working! Please help!

Comment: I used another plugin because it's created an issue when I generate build.